# Code android for a KitchenTimer

Tags: android, android-activity

> is there someone who can help me to find a android code to create a kitchen >timer (I am a beginner)

Comment: There are already a lot of very good Kitchen timers. For free. Do we need yet another one?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, not sure why you didn't just search Google. However I'd advise using the inbuilt `CountDownTimer` class. Here is an example of how to set it all up:

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-count-timer

Comment: i find many example like the one u posted but i need a code for timer with a navigation bar that i can move and select time

Comment: @AsmaKhedher Why do you need a navigation bar rather than up and down buttons?